# Bootstrap vertical pills nav not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've directly copy pasted a code snippet from the Bootstrap 4 docs on vertical pills (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior) into Codepen and I can't seem to get it to work.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ajayns/pen/vQoPNW?editors=1011n

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical" data-tabs="tabs">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">messages</div>
</div>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing out or doing wrong? I've checked this with a local setup and getting the same issue.

Comment: Please include jQuery 3 before bootstrap.js. which must be fix your problem.
Check this codepen https://codepen.io/shahjehan/pen/RqXdBY?editors=1111

Comment: Yes! It's working now, but I still seem to be facing the same bug locally.

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
use jquery before bootstrap.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include bootstrap 4 css and js

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical" data-tabs="tabs">
  <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="v-pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="v-pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-home-tab">home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-profile-tab">profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="v-pills-messages" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="v-pills-messages-tab">messages</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The provided code shows the tab content below the tab group not to the right-hand-side as it is supposed - Do you have a fix for this please?

Comment: @NoChance need to add padding: .5rem 1rem; to tab-content